# Matching rows of two tables by their attributes

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

Is there a way to match entities in plain PL/pgSQL?
Let's say I want to search a single person in a customer table by using a text search query that compares three single attributes to identify a match:

```
    SELECT id, first_name, last_name, birthdate
    FROM customers_index
    WHERE first_name @@ plainto_tsquery('simple','John')
        AND last_name @@ plainto_tsquery('simple','Smith')
        AND birthdate = '17.08.1967';
```

But doing this for every person is a bit tedious, because I have an entire table of persons that I want to match this way. With the help of any "normal programming language", I'd loop true an array now, until I'd found an existing match for every row as a new table, but is there a way to do this in plain PL/pgSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a function in PL/PGSQL (similar to Oracle's PL/SQL) combined with arrays as the input parameters would work nicely:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION customers(first_names text[], last_names text[],
    birthdays date[])
  RETURNS SETOF customers_index as
$BODY$
DECLARE
  i integer;
  elements integer;
  rw customers_index%rowtype;
BEGIN

  elements := array_length (first_names);

  for i in 1..elements loop

    for rw in SELECT ci.*
      FROM customers_index ci
      WHERE ci.first_name @@ plainto_tsquery('simple', first_names[i])
        AND ci.last_name @@ plainto_tsquery('simple', last_names[i])
        AND ci.birthdate = birthdays[i]
    loop
      return next rw;
    end loop;
  end loop;

  return;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

And the implementation would look something like this:

```
select
  id, first_name, last_name, birthdate
from
  customers(array['John', 'Jane'], array['Smith', 'Doe'], 
      array ['17.08.1967', '16.07.1970'])
```

If course, assuming your data comes from some other place, the actual implementation should look much cleaner.

Also, I don't promise this is super-efficient, but it would be a quick path from A to B, and with some GIN indexes, or at the very least an index on the birthdate it might actually run pretty nicely.

Comment: Thanks, I could create a working solution, based on your suggestion. Just a minor issue: array_length() needs two parameters, so array_length (first_names,1) did the job. Since nobody else gave a solution, I'll mark your solution as best answer.